# Why are floating point values truncated when stored in a variable in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

```
2> PI = 3.14159265358979323846264338.
3.141592653589793
3> PI.
3.141592653589793
```

What happened to the rest of the digits in the PI? How to get the complete value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Erlang and Big Numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250915/erlang-and-big-numbers)

Comment: Truth is that for most actual problems the value of Pi will be far more accurate than the other values in your calculations

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Erlang uses IEEE 754-1985 double precision (64-bit) floats, which have a precision of about 16 decimal digits. In other words, what you are seeing is expected.

You could of course also just use `math:pi/0`, which is `3.1415926535897932`.

Answer (score 3):

@Michael gave you a correct answer, just for fun I put here a small program that calculate an integer fraction which is as close as you want to the value of pi. It takes as parameter how many correct digits (at least) you want: K, and returns the tuple:
`{Pi*10^K, Num, Div}` and pi is approximated by `Num/Div`:

```
8> pi:pi(5).
{314159,1231847548,392109375}
9> 1231847548/392109375.
3.141591674516836
10> pi:pi(16).           
{31415926535897932,1954593375063141623418966719395892212,
 622166394751939884889125823974609375}
11> 1954593375063141623418966719395892212/622166394751939884889125823974609375.
3.141592653589793
12> pi:pi(100).                                                                
{31415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679,
 76687493427849560932551539133547355657552111418520642454352142367859087475777099790110509028596728165604330274537401085479755361074012954953620747810364589561632946227768531437131849315704805073879011158859557501594908388272923613955511642353579477204804,
 24410387304738988881243138674543333937873180956639377144249334863653319012629901313275720024646578388088082064861007931480541676642001787010751232779539604168044020067382957776693277819044947249055510862819577525863190547994463486247695982456207275390625}

-module (pi).

-export ([arctan/2,pi/1,pgcd/2,cf/2,fra/2]).

%% @doc
%% arctan({N:integer(),D:integer()},P:integer()) -> {N1:integer(),D1:integer()}
%% evaluate the value of arctan(N/D) with a precision of P digits
%% return the result as a fraction N1/D1
arctan({N,D},P) ->
    N2=N*N,
    D2=D*D,
    arctan([{N,D}],N2,D2,-1,3,N2*N,D2*D,P).

%% @doc
%% L is the list of {D,N} terms of the result,
%% N2 and D2 are the square values of initial N,D
%% S is the sign of the next term
%% 1/F is the coefficient of the next term of the serie
%% Nc/Dc is the next power of the initial N/D number
%% P the precision
arctan(L,_N2,_D2,_S,F,Nc,Dc,P) when P*Nc < F*Dc ->
    sumterm(L);
arctan(L,N2,D2,S,F,Nc,Dc,P) ->
    arctan([{S*Nc,F*Dc}|L],N2,D2,-S,F+2,Nc*N2,Dc*D2,P).

sumterm(L) ->
    D = lists:foldl(fun({_,X},A) -> X*A end,1,L),
    N =lists:foldl(fun({X,Y},A) -> X * D div Y + A end,0,L),
    {N,D}.

pi(P) ->
    P1 = list_to_integer(lists:reverse(string:chars($0,P,"1"))),
    {N1,D1} = arctan({1,5},32*P1),
    {N2,D2} = arctan({1,239},8*P1),
    N3 = 16*N1*D2 - 4*N2*D1,
    D3 = D1*D2,
    P3 = pgcd(D3,N3),
    N4 = N3 div P3,
    D4 = D3 div P3,
    {(N4*P1) div D4, N4, D4}.

-spec pgcd(non_neg_integer(),non_neg_integer()) -> non_neg_integer().
%% @doc Compute the greatest common divider of A and B
pgcd(A,B) when is_integer(A), is_integer(B), A >= 0, B >= 0 ->
    gcd(A,B).

-spec gcd(non_neg_integer(),non_neg_integer()) -> non_neg_integer().
gcd(A, B) when A < B -> gcd(B, A);
gcd(A, 0) -> A;
gcd(A, B) -> gcd(B, A rem B).


cf(P,Q) -> cf(P,Q,[]).

cf(P,1,L) -> lists:reverse([P|L]);
cf(P,Q,L) ->
    P1 = P div Q,
    Q1 = P rem Q,
    cf(Q,Q1,[P1|L]).

fra(L,N) ->
    N1 = min(length(L),N) -1,
    L1 = lists:sublist(L,N1),
    P = lists:nth(N1+1,L),
    fra(P,1,lists:reverse(L1)).

fra(N,D,[]) -> {N,D};
fra(N,D,[H|T]) -> fra(N*H+D,N,T).
```